# SQL query in C#, invalid object name T_Server_Info

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

There is a table named `T_Server_Info` in my database, however when I try to run my code by executing SQL query in C#, I get an error:

> Invalid object name T_Server_Info

Here is my code:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Constring = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";

    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(Constring);
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO T_Server_Info(FS_UID,Server_Name) VALUES(@FS_UID,@Server_Name)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FS_UID", uid.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server_Name", uid.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: can u post the table signature too

Comment: And is that table `T_Server_Info` really in the `Dev_Server` database? That's the database you're connecting to - is this the correct database to use?

Comment: yes that table is in Dev_Server

Comment: try Dev_server.dbo.T_Server_Info